# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have used formArray and now Iam doing validation on the array fields. Below is my code but when I click on Submit, I am getting

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined.

and the first line of html is highlighted in red on console. Please let me know the actual cause.

`app.component.html`

```
  <div *ngFor="let items of contractList.controls; let i=index" 
                [formGroupName]="i">
    <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr> 
     <td>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
          <label for="copay">Copay Amount:</label>
          <input formControlName="copay" placeholder="Copay Amount" class="form-control" name="copay" id="copay" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && items.get('copay').errors }">
        <div *ngIf="submitted && items.get('copay').errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                                <div *ngIf="items.get('copay').errors.required">Copay is required</div>
                            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
 get contractList() {
         return this.addForm.get('contractServiceList') as FormArray;
      }
      constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public router:
        Router, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, public contractService: ContractService) {
      }
    get f() { return this.addForm.controls; }

       arrayValidator() {
        return (control: FormArray) => {
          return null;
         }
      }
      createForm(data: any): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
          contractName: [data ? data.contractName : '', Validators.required],
          contractServiceList: this.formBuilder.array(
                 this.createContractService(data ? data.contractServiceList : null),this.arrayValidator()
                  )
          });
      }
      createContractService(data: any[]|null): FormGroup[] {
        return data ?
          data.map(x => {
            let group = this.formBuilder.group({
              serviceId: [x.serviceId, Validators.required],
              copay: [x.copay, Validators.required],
              coinsurance: [x.coinsurance, Validators.required],
              deductibleApplies: [x.deductibleApplies, Validators.required],
              penaltyApplies: [x.penaltyApplies, Validators.required],
              penaltyRule: [x.penaltyRule, Validators.required],
              penaltyType: [x.penaltyType, Validators.required],
              penaltyValue: [x.penaltyValue, Validators.required],
              deductibleAppliesPenalty: [x.deductibleAppliesPenalty, Validators.required]
                });
            return group;
          }) :
          [this.formBuilder.group(
            {
              serviceId: ['', Validators.required],
              copay: ['', Validators.required],
              coinsurance: ['', Validators.required],
              deductibleApplies: ['', Validators.required],
              penaltyApplies: ['', Validators.required],
              penaltyRule: ['', Validators.required],
              penaltyType: ['', Validators.required],
              penaltyValue: ['', Validators.required],
              deductibleAppliesPenalty: ['', Validators.required]
            })];
      }
      ngOnInit() {
         {
        this.addForm = this.createForm(null);
      }
      }

      onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        console.log(this.addForm.value);
        if (this.addForm.invalid) {
                return;
            }
        this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
          .subscribe( data => {
            if ( window.confirm('Contract created successfully') ) {
              this.addForm.reset();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something  like this:

Using Array `Index` here to get **controls** of form array

> I assumed form as addForm and formarray as contractServiceList

```
addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors
```

Or

```
addForm.controls.contractServiceList['controls'][i].get('copay').errors
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let items of contractList.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                        <label for="copay">Copay Amount:</label>
                        <input formControlName="copay" placeholder="Copay Amount" class="form-control" name="copay" id="copay">
                        <div *ngIf="addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors.required">Copay is required</div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked for me but I get a bug in my code that when I am going with a positive flow, the form is submitted and at last I am resetting the form. So on reset, the validation red error message comes which ideally should not happen. Validation should only come when I am clicking on Submit button. this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
      .subscribe( data => {
        if ( window.confirm('Contract created successfully') ) {
          this.addForm.reset();
        }
      }); This is the code for submit which I am using, let me know if there is something to be changed.

Comment: set control to touched/untouched to hide/show red mark

Comment: This is not the bug just  some change are required.

Comment: If not working create stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/ i will update your solution

Comment: Could you please add touched/untouched line of code into this piece and guide me how to add 
      <input ...... [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors }">
    <div *ngIf="submitted && addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="addForm.controls.contractServiceList.controls[i].controls.copay.errors.required">Copay is required</div>
                        </div>